Typescript can't see default properties in JSX
I expected it works:
interface Point {
  x: number;
  y: number;
}

function A({x, y}: Point = {x: 1, y: 1}) {
  return `x:${x}y:${y}`;
}

export default function App() {
  return <A/>; //error TS2739
}

export default function App() {
  return <>{A()}</>; //ok, no problem
}

Why it doesn't work?
ps.
Stackoverflow ask me to add some details, but I can't do that
because code explains problem well.
That is why I add this ps.

I'm no react expert, but what actually happens if you call App as written in your top example? Doesn't it print x:undefinedy:undefined? You want default properties, not default arguments, as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write an a or find a duplicate; if not, what's missing?

<A/> will result in calling A({}), which is invalid.

@jcalz what if I need x and y to be mandatory? But now I see it is impossible because we can't obligate jsx element attributes to be mandatory as all or nothing. Maybe that is the reason why it doesn't work

What do you mean by "mandatory"? If you want "all or nothing" then you can change the parameter type to be a union as shown here. Does that fully address the question now? Or am I still missing something?

@jcalz not optional

It doesn't make sense; if you want to accept <A /> then they are not "mandatory".

@jcalz { x = 1, y = 1 }: Point | { x?: never, y?: never } it is what I need! Thanks!

Okay then I'll write an answer soon.

When you write <A />, it ends up calling A({}) with an empty object as argument; it does not call A() with no argument. So you need to write A such that it accepts an empty object and does what you want with it.  In the comments you implied that you wanted to either require both x and y, or you want to prohibit both x and y. You don't want to make x and y independently optional.
If so then you need something like
type ProhibitKeysOf<T> = { [P in keyof T]?: never }
type EmptyObj = ProhibitKeysOf<Point>;
/* type EmptyObj = {
    x?: never;
    y?: never;
} */

function A({ x = 1, y = 1 }: Point | EmptyObj) {
    const r = `x:${x}, y:${y}`
    console.log(r);
    return r;
}

Note that TypeScript doesn't have a type that means "empty object" the way we're talking about it. If you write {} like Point | {} then it will accept anything at all, since {} means "a type with no known properties" which isn't the same as "a type known not to have properties".  So instead we can use {x?: never, y?: never} to mean a type where x and y are either missing or undefined.  My little ProhibitKeysOf<T> utility type is just there to show how to extend this to more properties if needed.
Note that there's no point in giving A a default argument like {x: 1, y: 1}, because A will never be called without an argument. Instead, you want something like default destructured properties, like {x = 1, y = 1} above, so that when you pass in {}, x and y get the default properties of 1.  This would technically mean if you pass in {x: 2} you'd get x is 2 and y is 1, which you don't want... but that possibility is precluded by the annotation Point | EmptyObj.
And now you can call A like:
<A x={1} y={2} />; // okay
<A x={1} />; // error
<A /> // okay

where you can pass in either both x and y or neither x nor y, and if you try passing just one then you get an error.
Playground link to code

I add some remark, your answer solved my problem, but looks like workaround. The real question, when you write , why does it end up calling with A({}) although typescript can see default argument {x:1, y:1} that can be used as A({x:1, y:1})

"why does it end up calling with A({})"? That's just how JSX works. It never calls the function without an argument. It doesn't decide whether or not to call A() or A({}) based on the implementation of A, that would be very difficult to imagine happening (what can "see" the default argument? TypeScript? React? By what mechanism would you propose calling A() or A({}) depending on the existence or lack thereof of a default argument)? So it's not a workaround, everything is behaving as intended.

as I understand typescript transform jsx markup to jsx(Dev) calls and substitute props

It transforms to React.createElement() which does what it does. It's really not up to TypeScript. I'm not sure what else to say here. It is simply a fact that <A /> maps to A({}) and not A(), and nothing I say or do can change that. That's the way it is. Are you looking for documentation to that effect?

In react-jsx mode it transforms to __jsx calls, but anyway typescript transforms jsx markup and can see default argument

In all cases, it's up to React what to do, and if React natively treats <A /> as A({}) and not A(), then TS has to transform it to something that does the same thing. Again, I'm not sure what we're trying to establish here. What can or should I do at this point?

The problem likely appears due to how default parameters and destructuring work in React.
When you call your function A() without arguments, it uses the default parameter.
However  when you use <A />, React passes an empty props object "{}" to A.
Function A then receives this empty object and tries to destructure x and y from it.
But because x and y are missing from the props object, their value will be undefined.
To solve your issue either you pass a value to your component
<A x={1} y={1} />

Or set x and y as optional in the interface
interface Point {
  x?: number;
  y?: number;
}

and then handle the undefined case for each property inside your "A" component function.
Lastly you need to return a valid jsx element and not a string.
Like this:
function A({x, y}: Point) {
  return <>{`x:${x}y:${y}`}</>;
}

Of course it is not required to be a React fragment
